# Parameter default ngMessages directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-messages

In order to do a little work around on AngularJS Material inputs, I would like to know if I can parameter all ngMessages directives *without create a new one* or add my attribute everywhere.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
    <label>Label</label>
    <input type="number" name="number" ng-model="number" min="0" max="10" required>
    <div ng-messages="form.number.$error" md-auto-hide="false"> <!-- mdAutoHide -->
        <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
        <div ng-message="min">Min is 0</div>
        <div ng-message="max">Max is 10</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Is there a solution to automatically add **mdAutoHide** attribute on all ngMessages?

Comment: I am going to try it, it is much needed relief when you really don't want to repeat ngMessages tags for 100's of input fields rather than add it as a element/attribute.So rather than 4 elements it would be just one element.Did you wanted that only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a directive specially for this.
This short code is wrong, cause it's a long time I didn't do angular js.
But yon can see the approach:

```
//directive
angular.module('app').directive('messageHidden', function () {
    var tpl = '<div>ng-messages="form.number.$error" md-auto-hide="false"></div>'
    for(var input in $scope.inputs){
        tpl += '<div ng-message="'+input.type+'">'"+input.message+"'</div>';
    }

    return {
         restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
       scope: {name: '@inputs'},
       template: tpl
   }
});



//ctrl
$scope.inputs = [
    {
        "type" : "required",
        "message" : "this is required"
    },
    {
        "type" : "min",
        "message" : "min is 0"
    },
    {
        "type" : "max",
        "message" : "max is 10"
    },

]
```

//view

```
<messageHidden inputs="$scope.inputs"/>
```

Comment: Of course I could write a directive, but I'd have to add it every time I use ngMessages directive: I don't want to; I'd like to setup globaly ngMessages directive for avoiding doing it everywhere.

Comment: If you write ngMessages, you could write your directive instead of.
You change nothing, you just override ngMessage with your directive.
I think ngMessage is dedicated to angular, you can't override it like you want, so I think the best way is to write a directive that will override ngMessages.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain how to override a _native_ directive?

Comment: I am going to try it, it is much needed relief when you really don't want to repeat ngMessages tags for 100's of input fields rather than add it as a element/attribute.So rather than 4 elements it would be just one element.

Comment: @bakouz : form.number.$error this is not dynamic? i have to hardcode the name, isnt there a way to make it dynamic so i can invoke this for different input fields and pass on the name dynamically.